# Document and ContentVersion

Tags: document, contentversion

I am trying to understand the relation between documents and contentversion.  When i queried documents, it returned 100+ records but when i queried contentversion it returned only 1.  Please help me understand the relation between them.  Plan is to move to lightning so doing some groundwork. Also i read to write some trigger on documents write it on contentversion.  How these 2 are related?

Answer (score 1):

> **[Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm)**
>
> Represents a file that a user has uploaded. Unlike Attachment records,
> documents are not attached to a parent object.
>
> **[ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)**
>
> Represents a specific version of a document in
> Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files. This object is available
> in versions 17.0 and later for Salesforce CRM Content documents. This
> object is available in versions 20.0 and later for Salesforce Files.

[Differences Between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=0)

There is no relation between these 2 objects.

[Moving Documents to Salesforce Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=docs_documents_to_files.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

> **How do I move files from the Documents tab into Lightning Experience?**
>
> While there isn’t a one-click solution, you do have some
> options once you identify the files in the Documents tab that you want
> to use in Lightning Experience and your communities.
>
> - Export documents in the weekly export, and then upload the documents    into Salesforce Files
> - Use a third-party data export tool from the AppExchange, like    FileExporter from Salesforce Labs
> - Use an API-based tool (The Chatter REST API supports uploading asset files.)

Comment: When moving to lightning as documents are not supported by lightning, i was asked consider moving to Salesforce file to do that i was asked to run a report on contentversion, so what does that mean?